# Drive access permissions

Tags: permissions

My daughters user account, if set to administrator, can open drives on the computer and browse/use files, no password required.

If I set her account to Standard user, she loses access to the drives unless she enters my admin password.

Is there a way for me to set her account as standard, however allow her access to a particular hard drive and all the contents therein ?

Comment: Possible duplicate on Unix & Linux: [Mount device with r/w access to specific user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30268/117037)

Comment: If you need more details, check the mount options available for your filesystem in [`man mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.8.html), under "FILESYSTEM-SPECIFIC MOUNT OPTIONS".

Comment: If you need easier instructions, you'll need to [edit] your question to include more details, like the filesystem type(s), and whether the drives are automatically mounted on startup. By the way, welcome to Ask Ubuntu!